# How can I generate the html code for a drop-down inside a controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a javascript function, part of which has a section that accepts HTML code. Right now, I have the following line in that javascript code:

```
html: `@Html.Action("Position","Admin")`
```

My issue is that my Position view has only one line in it:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PositionId",null,htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
```

However, I feel like it's a waste to have an entire View created with just one line. I'm only using the view because I need to generate the HTML for the DropDownList via Razor to pass to my function.

How can I generate the resulting HTML code in my controller without having to create a view?

Comment: HTML is just a string of text, right?. So sure, you *could*.

Comment: Apologies if my question wasn't clear. I meant to ask how, not if I could. I'll go ahead and update my question. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a good practice to have HTML in controller. Creating view file is the way to go.

Comment: `string someHtml = "<p>Hello, world!</p>";` there. It's some HTML you can declare in your controller. Now you just need to return it from your controller, but surely you can find that out too by with a bit of research?

Comment: If it was just a matter of writing HTML in a string and passing it from my controller, then I would never had made a post here in the first place. I am not asking how to store HTML in a string. I am asking how I can generate HTML code from within my controller using the DropDownList that Razor provides. At present, Razor generates the resulting HTML code for my dropdown list as the view is rendered. I want to have this created entirely in the controller.